# how to add jquery-slider to the dependency list in browserify?

Tags: browserify, reactjs-flux, jquery-slider

Description : I have package.json and bower.json for handling dependencies in my current schema. In which file should I add the **"jquery.slider (version 1.1.0)"** and how to do it?.
Currently,I have added the dependency in bower.json like below

```
"dependencies": {
        "jquery.slider": "^1.1.0" 
    }
```

I have also tried it added in package.json and also in both ,but the slider is not even getting displayed.
Can anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

You could install it with `npm`, so it would be added to your `package.json` automatically.

```
npm install --save jquery.slider
```

> **Note** the `--save` option within the command. This will add the module to the dependencies.

Then, if someone will clone the project he can simply run

```
npm install
```

to install all dependencies defined in `package.json`, included `jquery.slider`, automatically.